# Pandas: adding columns into by mapping when there are several keys in the dictionnary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, mapping

Here is my problem, I would like to map a dictionary in a DataFrame but I cannot find a way to do that when the dictionary has several keys. Note that these keys are present in different columns in the DataFrame.

Here is an example:

this is the dataframe I have at the begining, df:

```
        Index      key 
0          10       k1       
1          12       k2   
2           3       k1    
3          34       k3
```

here is the dictionary I have, d:

```
{('k1', 10):v1,('k1', 3):v2,('k2', 12):v3,('k3', 34):v4}
```

I would like to have at the end, df:

```
        Index      key    value
0          10       k1       v1    
1          12       k2       v2
2           3       k1       v3
3          34       k3       v4
```

is there a way to do that the same way that you can do that when you have a one key dictionary :

> df["value"] = df["key"].map(d)

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC using `merge`

```
mergedf=pd.Series(d).reset_index()
mergedf.columns=['key','Index','values']
df.merge(mergedf,how='left')
Out[642]: 
   Index key values
0     10  k1     v1
1     12  k2     v3
2      3  k1     v2
3     34  k3     v4
```

Answer (score 3):

Use list comprehension with `get` for return `None` for no matched values:

```
df['value'] = [d.get(x) for x in zip(df['key'], df['Index'])]
print (df)
   Index key value
0     10  k1    v1
1     12  k2    v3
2      3  k1    v2
3     34  k3    v4
```

---

```
d = {('k1', 10):'v1',('k1', 3):'v2',('k2', 12):'v3'}

df['value'] = [d.get(x) for x in zip(df['key'], df['Index'])]
print (df)
   Index key value
0     10  k1    v1
1     12  k2    v3
2      3  k1    v2
3     34  k3  None
```